# Google chrome doesn't display personal certificate

Tags: google-chrome, certificate, personal-data

I'm testing some webservices that use certificates for authentication. So basically I've added to certificate store some custom root CA and some client certificate to personal folder.

When I open Chrome advanced settings - manage certificates button this personal certificates is missing, though it is installed and visible in certmgr.

Can you please advise what may cause this behaviour? I can't authenticate without this certificate being used by chrome.

Update: Latest chrome release, windows server 2012

Comment: What operating system.  Chrome uses the operating system's certificate store.  It doesn't sound like you have told the OS to trust the certificate.

Comment: @Ramhound updated info

Comment: Is IE aware of the certificates?

Comment: As such is visible this certificate in certmgr?

Comment: @RomeoNinov certificate is displayed in certmgr

Comment: @Ramhound How am I supposed to check it in IE?

Comment: In which section? There are CA, server certificates, personal certificates?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, CA is installed in trusted root folder.

Comment: I ask about your certificate. It should be in personal certificates. Otherwise will not work

Comment: @RomeoNinov it is in personal, but still not visible in google chrome.

Comment: Have you try accessing the site with other browser?

Comment: @RomeoNinov As I've found out IE also doesn't display this certificate.

Comment: Do you add it with private key?

Comment: @RomeoNinov it has no keys, it's public "cer" file

Comment: So you can't use it as authentication. You need the key for your personal certificate

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks, that's really was an issue. Maybe you'll make an answer, so I can vote it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion above I understand that the personal certificate is installed. In the proper place in Microsoft certification store. The OP try to use this certificate as authentication mechanism. Unfortunately this is not possible because OP have only the certificate (signed by CA public key) but do not have private key for this certificate. And private key is required for the purpose of authentication

Comment: This was the result of our issue with Unipass. Certificate needs to be a pfx file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the private key of the certificate , then you can create a p12 certificate and install it in chrome , then it will list your certificate when accessing the url

Creating a p12 is explained here
https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/288.html